# Is there an API to add products to aliexpress orders list

Tags: aliexpress

Is there an API to send products from my app to aliexpress orders list, shopmaster (a shopping software) does this by firstly authenticating the user's account with an oauth2 authentication and then orders can be added from shopmaster to aliexpress directly, i plan on doing something similar but i havent found an API or anything similar.
Any idea will be appreciated